# In SDLC, What are the things covered by "Design"?

Tags: sdlc

Is it the flow diagram, User Interface or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the design phase of the SDLC, making solution is focused via system modeling. Uml modeling is performed which is called the Unified modeling language. UML modeling has the following steps

- Class diagram
- Use case diagram
- Collaboration diagram
- Sequence diagram

The UML modeling is basically for defining the problem or we can say it is a tool to solve the problem.

More : http://websolace.net/web-design-solutions/sdlc-maintains-the-quality/

Comment: Thanks. Right now I've been doing good when it comes to modelling diagrams. :)

Answer (score 0):

From wikipedia:

In systems, design functions and operations are described in detail, including screen layouts, business rules, process diagrams and other documentation. The output of this stage will describe the new system as a collection of modules or subsystems.
The design stage takes as its initial input the requirements identified in the approved requirements document. For each requirement, a set of one or more design elements will be produced as a result of interviews, workshops, and/or prototype efforts. Design elements describe the desired software features in detail, and generally include functional hierarchy diagrams, screen layout diagrams, tables of business rules, business process diagrams, pseudocode, and a complete entity-relationship diagram with a full data dictionary. These design elements are intended to describe the software in sufficient detail that skilled programmers may develop the software with minimal additional input.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_Development_Life_Cycle#Design

Answer (score 0):

In SDLC (Software Development Life Cycle), given below things covered in Designing phase:

- Partition of requirements into hardware & software system.
- Designing system architecture.
- Creating UML diagrams (class diagram, Use cases, sequence diagrams
  and Activity diagram)